# Why does my Ambient Occlusion bake and Exported UV Layout have color from my materials?

Tags: uv, texture-baking, ambient-occlusion

I have created an object and I have assigned a bunch of materials, each with different diffuse colors (for use in dDo) to different parts of the model. What I can't figure out is why when I bake my Ambient Occlusion map I am getting color information in my AO Map. *Clear* is the only item that I have checked in the Bake Settings. I am also getting the same behavior when I export my UV layout. I don't think I have ever seen this before and I am totally stumped. I don't have any vertex colors on the model. I have no textures in the scene either as I removed them by holding down Shift and unlinking the datablock for my texture bakes. I have cleared all those out and restarted Blender. All I have is my model and a whole bunch of materials with different diffuse colors, that I have assigned to different parts of the mesh. What would be causing such a thing to happen?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In BI the diffuse color is used to color AO output.

One way to avoid this is to enable *Normalized* in the bake settings:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That definitely solved the AO map problem having color information. I am still continuing to look for a solution to eliminate color information for the UV Layout map since I know of no way to alter settings there.

Comment: @BrysonJack Hm.. I can't think of anything besides I quick python script to set all the diffuse colors to white (either running on a backup .blend or storing the values in an array for setting them back later). If that's not acceptable, does desaturating the UV map work well enough?

Comment: Well, if Blender isn't misbehaving, or I didn't accidentally change a setting somewhere and that is the normal behavior then I will have to come up with some kind of workaround. I really appreciate your help gandalf3.